# unit testing async express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, testing

I have the following async middleware which uses multiple try-catches to check for the response of some http calls. I wish to unit test this middleware but am encountering difficulties mocking the "next" callback. When i wrap it like so:

```
it('should test for auth', () => {
    logon(req, res, function() {
        expect(res.locals).toBe(true)
    })
})
```

it does not seem to be actually running the function and running the `expect` after. Any ideas on how I can mock the `request`, `response` and `next` objects so I can test for the final values (res.locals)? Thanks.

```
async function logon(req, res, next) {

if (!req.query.isAuth)
    req.locals.auth = false;
    next()
}

try {
    const getData = await http.get(/logon);
    if (getData.status == 200) {
        res.locals.auth = true;
    } else {
        res.locals.auth = false;
        try {
            const secondCall = http.get(/logon2);
            if (secondCall.data.bob) {
                return res.redirect(/home);
            }
        } catch(e) {console.error(3)}
    }
} catch(e) {console.error(e)}
next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make req, res and next as empty objects(stubs) with some minimal api, and check changes on them, after your function, runs on them. For stubs/mocks/spies you may also use ready made, with sinon.js https://sinonjs.org or jest